# Query MongoDB document array with single value

Tags: mongodb

I have the following doc structure in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5419a68bb4a638dae0d63af1"),
    "id" : NumberLong(24),
    "name" : "Facebook test",
    "type" : NumberLong(3),
    "fb_pages" : [ 
        NumberLong(147899715380422)
    ],
    "staff_selectable" : true,
    "background_colour" : "fffcfe",
    "text_colour" : "600009",
    "border_colour" : "df0077"
}
```

I need to select the first document against the `fb_pages` property. `fb_pages` is an array of facebook page id's. However when I query for that document it will be with one facebook page id. Like this:

```
db.widgets.find({fb_pages: 147899715380422})
```

This doesn't return anything so I'm guessing it's because `fb_pages` is an array not an int.

Any idea how I can query that?

Comment: It should work. I copy your code and succeed to fetch the document. What's the version of MongDB you are running?

Comment: yes , even your version should work too......

Comment: Oh dear I had the collection name wrong. Doh! Sorry guys :$

Answer (score 0):

use the $in operator (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/ )

```
db.widgets.find({fb_pages: {$in: [147899715380422]}})
```

even this should work:

```
db.widgets.find({fb_pages: [147899715380422]})
```

Comment: As Wizard already commented, this isn't needed as only a single value is being queried for.